# send checkbox value in php

Tags: php, checkbox

Does anyone knows how to code in php for every time i tick the check-box in my form?
And when i tick the check-box,the value is suppose to actually inserted into an id column in my database and it will auto increase every time i tick and submit the form.

Comment: what did you tried sofar?

Comment: Question not clear...

Comment: @donald123 '$cbox = $_POST['tickExam']; 

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($cbox); $i++) { 
$query1 ="INSERT INTO exam VALUES ('".$cbox."')";
}'

Comment: @Julo0sS my question is that in my view page i have a table and few records is being displayed in the table. Now i have a checkbox displayed beside each of the data row, so if everytime I tick the checkbox of one the rows,i want the checkbox to send a value to an id column in my database(and each time the value will increase by 1).

Comment: what do you mean with value increased by 1 ? Some field in the database is increased each time you post your form with field checked?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax. Following is the code snippet.

```
$('input:radio[name="tickExam"]').click(function() {
if(this.checked){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'increase.php',
            data: {id:$(this).val()},
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Increased.....');
            },
             error: function() {
                alert('Sorry! there was an issue');
            }
        });

        }
  });
```

in increase.php write your code to increase value in table.

Comment: what do u mean "code to increase value in table"? u mean i have to do a insert php page and in the page i have to write a for loop? Does this means every time i tick on the checkbox,will it automatically increase the value in the id column of a table?

Comment: Sorry, I was meant to insert id in a column in your table.

Comment: im not sure if i completely understand the statement above but heres a scenario that im facing. - my question is that in my view page i have a table and few records is being displayed in the table. Now i have a checkbox displayed beside each of the data row, so if everytime I tick the checkbox of one the rows,i want the checkbox to send a value to an id column in my database(and each time the value will increase by 1).- Do you have any idea how to create the code?

Comment: PHP generates an HTML page in the server, and sends it to the requester user. You cannot manipulate what happens in the client-side from PHP, that's why you need javasript. Ajax is an architecture that allows you to communicate asynchronously with the server, and so make new requests for some PHP file in the server to generate some content and send it back to javascript. Then javascript can do whatever is needed.

Your question is not easy to understand because you seem not to know when and where each thing is running. I strongly recommend you to find some diagram on Google

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have this :

```
<form ...>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            //...
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' value='YOUR_ID' name='checkboxarray[]'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name='submit' type='submit' ...>
</form>
```

You want that on submit, the corresponding ID database record "counter field" to be increased by 1 'IF THE BOX IS CHECKED'

then, do that :

```
//if you posted : 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //here you have to handle your data
    //your checkbox array is not empty IF there is something checked, so : 
    if(is_array($_POST['checkboxarray'])){
        foreach($_POST['checkboxarray'] as $value){
            //HERE YOUR $VALUE IS THE ID OF THE DB RECORD (if you dit id the way I explain it over), so do your database stuff here, just increase your field WHERE id = $value !
        }
    }else{
        //no checkboxes checked
    }
}else{
    //nothing posted, just display your form
}
```

Is that what you need?

> Does anyone knows how to code in php for every time i tick the check-box in my form? And when i tick the check-box,the value is suppose to actually inserted into an id column in my database and it will auto increase every time i tick **and submit the form**.

considering your post when you say "every time i tick AND SUBMIT THE FORM", then there is no need to use javascript or ajax in your case

Comment: do you mind giving an example of the database statement? i only know basic db statement like insert and select. im not sure on how to like increase the id =$value.

Comment: @ayowhassup Well, I don't know anything about your database... usually you don't have to increase manually your id's if you have a serial sequence... This is just as simple as an insert or an update statement, what is your db? postgresql? mariadb? else?

Comment: When you are in the foreach loop, $value = the value of the checkbox checked (which corresponds to a database id as you said). So, you know, that database record with id = $value has been checked... am I clear enough? ^^ :)